# Searching Text with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to tackle a PC parts listing for my website utilizing a MySQL database to make it easier on me in the long run...it's all going well until I need to do a bit of text searching.

This is where I'm at:

```
database name: _staff
table name: parts
```

I need to `SELECT * FROM itemName MATCH ("Processors:%");`

Essentially I need to find all rows in this table where the `itemName` column begins with "Processors:"

The strings are colon delimited names preceded by [category]:  .... if that is of any use :)

Ideas?

Comment: Better create a table that only stores processors

Comment: Unfortunately that is how Quickbooks (where I keep my parts/inventory) exported it to CSV. They are actually colon-delimited categories that are appended to the beginning of the string. Adding this to the question since it might be helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think maybe:

```
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE itemName LIKE 'Processors%';
```

Comment: just remove the colon after Processors

Comment: He had the colon on the original question so I left it.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid...I just realized I was searching the wrong column :(

For the record, this was what worked (when I did it right):
     SELECT * FROM 'parts' WHERE itemName LIKE 'Processors%';

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Try removing the colon then, as @SyedQarib said. I edited the answer. If it still returns empty, could you please provide some sample data to run SQL fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM parts WHERE itemName LIKE 'Processors:%';
```

see demo here ..http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5e85/2

Comment: Although this isn't the answer to this specific question, thanks because it is actually a gentle shove in the right direction as far as integrating all this into the PHP